# Error with concatenating list to string in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to pass class element to method. Element is formed dynamically inserting current time in it. Mine class looks something like this:

```
class MineContact(dict):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        # set your default values
        import time
        curr_time = repr(time.time()).replace('.', '') 
        self['givenName'] = ['name%s' % curr_time[10:]]
        ...
```

So, I create object of this class and now I want to insert it as method argument:

```
    contact = MineContact()
    extra_text = "-%d" % (self.iteration)
    new_contact.insert_given_name(contact.givenName + extra_text)
```

When I run this script, I get this type of error:

> TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list

So, does anyone knows where am I getting it wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`givenName` seems to be a list. You can append another list like this:

```
new_contact.insert_given_name(contact.givenName + [extra_text])
```

Answer (score -1):

contact.givenName is a list, and extra_text is a string. in python you can add string to string, or list to list. you can't add string to list.

if you'd like to add string to a list, use list.append method.

```
mylist.append(mystr)
```

Comment: That modifies the existing list which is not what the OP is trying to do.

Comment: Also, that will pass `None` when passed as a function parameter since list.append(val) returns `None`

Comment: I am telling him how to concatate list and string. why you think I give him code to copy and paste?

Comment: Your approach is fundamentally wrong - the code will not work in his use case. The `.append()` method can be used to append a string to an existing list, not to create a new list from a given list, extended by one element.